# How to inspect a brand new motorcycle before buying from showroom?

Tags: engine, kawasaki

When you decide to buy a brand new bike from an official Suzuki, Kawasaki or Yamaha showroom, how can you inspect to be sure of that the bike is brand new with zero mileage?

What if the bike has been used few hundreds miles and sold / returned back by the first owner again to the showroom, refurbished and polished and put on display?

Comment: I have deleted the parts that don't help the question, and in fact make it worse. Clocking is less and less possible with modern bikes/cars, and documents are much easier to check. Even wanting zero miles is not relevant - no vehicle will have zero miles new.

Comment: @RoryAlsop A few years back I purchased a new 2005 Honda GL1800 that was literally taken out of the crate by the dealer and assembled in the parking lot.  It had 0.0 miles showing on it.  I assume it had some distance on it but it was less than the limit of the odometer which was 0.1 miles.

Comment: Okay - I take that back. Lowest I have seen is 14 miles. I'd always prefer at least a couple of miles to prove to me they have at least driven it round the block.

Comment: @jwh20 I knew a tester who jumped on a new bike (assembled out of the crate) and ran it the length of the runway and into the river at the end - mechanic forgot to connect the brake. So a thorough test is usually a good idea:)

Answer (score 2):

Cars and bikes always have a few miles on the clock as they have road test etc.

Dealers also sell **very** low mileage examples as they have been used for the sales staff and road tests for clients usually at a significant discount.

But as for selling a second hand as new then you must have some real cowboys where you are. And I worked for a Main Dealer and have experience of prepping new cars, sorting issues under warranty etc etc.

Going in with your eyes open and not accusing them straight off the bat may help.

Answer (score 1):

A new motor vehicle should have a COA or Certificate of Origin from the manufacturer, such as Kawasaki.  If it has one of those it's new.

A previously owned motor vehicle will have an existing title in the previous owner's name.

You should be able to inspect the paperwork for the vehicle you are preparing to purchase.

This, however, is not universal throughout the world, so in your particular location you may need to rely on your own inspection.  Look for signs of wear, damage, dirt or grease on the inside of the fenders, etc.  A few miles on the odometer is normal for a new motorcycle, more than a few should have a reasonable explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it is like a new car. Check if it is the color you ordered and drive it away. I have only bought a few ( 6 ) brand new vehicles from GM and Nissan, never a problem if something need service under warrantee.